# How to push incomplete parts in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code iterates an array, and generates Reacts components in a row.

```
var row = [];
IconsAndTexts.forEach(function(IconObject) {
  if (IconObject.badge !== 0) {
    rows.push(
      <Col xs sm md lg
        <table key={"1." + IconObject.key}>

        </table>
      </Col>
    );
  }
});

return (rows);
```

I omitted some of my inner workings but it basically works as described.
 My question is how can I push to a row only part of an element(For example, i would want to push only the beggining of a column `<Col>` at first, and then push the closing tag `</Col>` after some calculations, but react won't let me do this).

So, how can i do it? Can i use strings and then push them?

Edit - Clarifying what i want to do, from my comment

It won't allow me to do this

```
rows.push(< Col xs sm md lg>);  
rows.push(< table key={"1." + IconObject.key}>);  
rows.push(< /Col>);
```

And it would be really useful if i could do it, because i would dynamically load my elements with more freedom, manipulating multiple elements without this becomes stiffer and harder.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying. This will push whatever JSX is in the `<Col>` tags. What are you saying it won't do? All JSX does is transpile into `createElement` calls, which return a value.

Comment: It won't allow me to do this    
    rows.push(<Col xs sm md lg>);  
    rows.push(<table key={"1." + IconObject.key}>);  
    rows.push(</Col>);  

And it would be really useful to do it, i could dynamically load my elements with more freedom, manipulating multiple elements without this becomes stiffer and harder.

Comment: No, that wouldn't make any sense-that's like trying to push a closing tag as a separate component, which isn't logical.

Comment: Does my answer below help ?

Comment: @DaveNewton I would say it's logical because i would render a whole componente, but would push only part of the component.

Comment: @ArshabhAgarwal it actually did, i was able to add tags as i wanted by putting them in the return statement, thanks

Comment: @EliaMelfiorSoftExpert That's not how it works. A "component" by definition is a wrapper around its children. There's no such thing as "the end of a component" on its own: a component is a wrapper, full stop. I don't see any reason you'd need to do what it is you're trying to do, either; there's nothing "less flexible" about the way it actually works.

Comment: @DaveNewton But the reason is evident, i may be misunderstanding something, but i think that conditionally adding another beginning of a <Col> which will be closed afterwards is something good. 
Reacts forces you to render only one thing inside this "wrapper", but in my mind, i was adding lines of jsx to an array, and not on my final component, so it would be a limitation in flexibility not being able to add an opening or closing tag as i wanted.    
You are forced to push whole "wrappers" to an array, and this limits the freedom you would have to create your components.

Comment: @EliaMelfiorSoftExpert How? What practical limitation does this impose? I've *never* had this need, or even wished I had this capability, and I've created some fairly complex components, including multiple levels of nested hierarchies with dynamic components. I just don't see the usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your tables in the `Col` tags like this and return.

```
IconsAndTexts.forEach(function(IconObject) {            
        if (IconObject.badge !== 0) {               
            rows.push(                  
                    <table key={"1." + IconObject.key}>

                    </table>
                );  
        }
    });
return <Col xs sm md lg>{rows}</Col>;
```

Comment: I managed to do what i wanted with different returns, so this answer lead me to the answer.